# PlayOnLinux window size can't be changed and buttons are hidden

Tags: software-installation, wine, window, playonlinux

I have an issue with Play On Linux. When I try to install a new program, the button to install a non-listed program is hidden and there is no way to resize the window. Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks.

[image: Here's a screenshot]

Comment: Does the key sequence of `Alt+Space, X` maximize the window?

Comment: No it doesn't. By the way, I am using GNOME desktop environment.

Comment: There is no  option to maximize the window.

Comment: See https://www.playonlinux.com/en/issue-5043.html

Comment: I fixed this issue by disabling communitheme. Thanks for help.

Comment: Good find, you should write that as an answer.  =)

Comment: Linked issue is just a WSOD.. Updated link?

Comment: [snapshot from Wayback Machine for Terrance's link](https://web.archive.org/web/20170715200118/https://www.playonlinux.com/en/issue-5043.html)