# 18.04 playonlinux extremley frustrating bug

Tags: 18.04, playonlinux

When I click the insall button on PlayOnLinux, the window is too small and it doesn't allow me to stretch it out. Why this is a problem is because it doesn't show the "Install an unlisted program" button. I've done some research but no one else has my problem. It did work fine before but no it doesn't. Edit: The window looks like this [image]

Comment: This was asked earlier and someone tried a different theme and it fixed it.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1044880/window-size-issue?noredirect=1#comment1703777_1044880  There is something that I can test a little more out where you change a setting in a configuration file for PlayOnLinux as well to maybe extend the window a little deeper.  Oh, and we can't fix bugs here,  They need to be filed correctly.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug

Comment: I found the config file for playonlinux, I have it opened right now. What do I change

Comment: It is found in a Variables.py file and it is 52 lines down.  Make the `windows_add_size =` to something greater than 25.  Something like 50 or 75.

Comment: The file is in read only mode and I can't change because it says "You are not the owner so you can't change the permissions." how do you fix that?

Comment: You have to edit it with sudo in front of the command.  It is owned by root.

Comment: When I drag the file to the terminal and put sudo in front of it, I get "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/playonlinux/python/lib/Variables.py", line 6, in <module>
    import wx, lib.playonlinux as playonlinux
ImportError: No module named lib.playonlinux
" How do I fix that?

Comment: Use the command in terminal:  `pkexec gedit /usr/share/playonlinux/python/lib/Variables.py` and edit it that way.

Comment: When I try to run it, I get "Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(gedit:6228): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:50:55.871: cannot open display: 
"

Answer (score 2):

This is only a temporary work around and the [problem should be filed as a bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) appropriately.

The following line will change the size of the add window in PlayOnLinux.  Copy and paste it to a terminal window to change the size:

```
sudo sed -i 's/windows_add_size = 25/windows_add_size = 75/' /usr/share/playonlinux/python/lib/Variables.py
```

To undo the changes copy and paste this line:

```
sudo sed -i 's/windows_add_size = 75/windows_add_size = 25/' /usr/share/playonlinux/python/lib/Variables.py
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It still doesn't work. The command changed line 52 to "windows_add_size = 75" but it still thinks the size is 25. I've experimented with higher numbers but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @agamer569 Try maybe taking it as high as 250.  Beyond that, try a different theme then or look into the possibility of a different desktop environment.  Some tests I ran in 18.04 did not show this but I use Xubuntu (Xfce4).  It does not have this issue, or at least I cannot duplicate your issue.

Comment: 259 worked! Thank so so much! By the way, i've been avoiding the xfce4 desktop because it runs very slowly in my opinion.

Comment: @agamer569 You just gotta know how to tweak things.  I know that GNOME over the last week has had 52 bugs filed where Xfce4 has only had 11.   It has never been slow for me, in fact it has been fast.  But, each to their own about the Linux desktop environments whatever works the best for the job.

Comment: a value of 100 works for me. But this only fixes the height. How to increase the width?